# Búsqueda en un arreglo de cadenas con otro arreglo de cadenas

Tags: java, java-8

buenas con todos tengo 2 arreglos que llamo de la base de datos

```
        listat = personNE.list(); //81 datos de todas las personas
        listap = personNE.list0121();  // 18 datos los que tienen seguro          

        int inter1 = listat.size();
        int interp = listap.size();
```

el problema que quiero comparar dos string y no lo compara quiero mostrar personas que tienen seguro y que no tienen

```
for (int i = 0; i < inter1; i++) {
            boolean Encontre = false;
            for (int j = 0; j < interp; j++) {
            //for (Person pe : listap) {
//if (listat.get(i).getCEDULA() == listap.get(j).getCEDULA())  //if que prove
//if(listap.get(j).getCEDULA().equals(listat.get(i).getCEDULA() )) // otro if que prove
                if (Arrays.asList(listap.get(j).getCEDULA()).contains(listat.get(i).getCEDULA()) )
                {
                    Encontre    =   true;

                }else 
                    Encontre = false;

            }
            if (!Encontre) {
                pw.println(String.valueOf(listat.get(i).getCODIGO_DOC()
                        + "|" + listat.get(i).getCEDULA() + "|" + "0" + "|"
                        + "0" + "|" + "|" + 1 + "|"));
            }else{
                pw.println(String.valueOf(listat.get(i).getCODIGO_DOC()
                        + "|" + listat.get(i).getCEDULA() + "|" + "0" + "|"
                        + "1" + "|" + "|" + 1 + "|"));
            }


        }
```

Espero su ayuda gracias

Comment: Puedes comparar toda la lista o tiene que ser solo ese String?

Comment: solo ese String que seria su numero de documento para ver quienes estan asegurado y quienes no

Comment: el problema es q no me hace la busqueda no lo filtra

Comment: Por favor agrega un [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes comparar las listas usando un `contains` que te va ayudar a saber si existe ese elemento de la lista solo la debes de recorrer con el `for` que ya tienes y seria de esta siguiente manera:

```
for (personNE per: listat) {
     if (listap.contains(per)) {
            System.out.println("Se encontró una coincidencia" + per);
            break;
        }

for (int i = 0; i < listat.size(); i++) {
  if (listat.get(i).getCampoAComparar.equals(per.getCampoAComparar)) {
System.out.println("Se encontró una coincidencia" + per);
    break;
  }

}
```

Pon el per.el campo que quieres comparar

> **Nota:** Yo puse un `break` para que finalice el ciclo pero es opcional si lo quieres quitar.

Comment: Gracias lo pruebo haber como me va

Comment: no funciona sigue sin comparar

Comment: @Dalstron modifique la respuesta prueba solo cambia el get de la lista por el campo que quieres modificar y per.getcampo también

Comment: lo comparare gracias